# QGIS web client ( I ) crashes

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

I installed and configured the qgis client ( Version 1 ). It works for the "Hello world" map, but anything else ( e.g. naturalearth ), causes the mapserv fcgi to crash. I tried to figure out what is going on, but I can't figure it out.

I tried installing GWC 2, but couldn't even get pass the yarn command.

I am new to QGIS, so can someone bring me up to speed on the web client i.e. which one to install and how?

---

I am running qgis 2.18.16 on Ubuntu 16.04 . I pulled the qgis web clinet from Github. As I mentioned it works for the hello world map, but not for anything more complex. When I try, for example with naturalearth_110million.qgs, I see this error in the Apache error log:

```
[fcgid:error] [pid 28782] mod_fcgid: process /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi(28791) 
exit(communication error).
```

Can you tell me how can I run the fcgi from the command line with the appropriate parameters?

Comment: It is important to provide more platform information and bugs to help you. What operating system are you using? which version of QGIS are you using? What are the errors you get when installing qwc2?

Comment: You could try looking into the apache logs. But if your fcgi fails, you should try running the executable itself, that will show you if your fcgi server is actually able to start. There could be some other completly different problem, so it would help if you told us what you tried and where (OS) like SamTux.